# xPath retrieving the wrong text

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I need to get two distinct instagram pseudos with xpath.

I have one block of html with 2 blocks where there are the pseudos. The first xpath give me the first pseudo but the second one also give me the first one instead of the second pseudo !

Code :

```
waiting = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@style='flex-direction: column; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 0px;']/div[@role='button']")

for w in waiting:
    print(w.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
    print('Pseudo : ',w.find_element_by_xpath("//div[2]/div/a").text)
```

What I get :

```
<div class="cek9Q">
    <div class="H59PT">
        <div class="RR-M- " role="button" tabindex="0">
            <canvas class="CfWVH" height="44" width="44" style="position: absolute; top: -5px; left: -5px; width: 44px; height: 44px;"></canvas>
            <a class="_2dbep qNELH kIKUG" href="/pseudo2/" style="width: 34px; height: 34px;"><img alt="pseudo1's profile picture" class="_6q-tv" src=""></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="YFq-A">
    <div class="_7WumH"><a class="FPmhX notranslate  yrJyr" title="pseudo2" href="/pseudo1/">pseudo1</a><span class="_8g-5H">Pseudo1</span></div>
</div>
Pseudo : pseudo1


<div class="cek9Q">
    <div class="H59PT">
        <div class="RR-M- " role="button" tabindex="0">
            <canvas class="CfWVH" height="44" width="44" style="position: absolute; top: -5px; left: -5px; width: 44px; height: 44px;"></canvas>
            <a class="_2dbep qNELH kIKUG" href="/pseudo2/" style="width: 34px; height: 34px;"><img alt="pseudo2's profile picture" class="_6q-tv" src=""></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="YFq-A">
    <div class="_7WumH"><a class="FPmhX notranslate  yrJyr" title="pseudo2" href="/pseudo2/">pseudo2</a><span class="_8g-5H">Pseudo2</span></div>
</div>
Pseudo : pseudo1  # This must be pseudo2 !!
```

Do you understand why it gives me pseudo1 instead of pseudo2 in the second case ? I cannot display all my code but I have printed a debug with get_attribute('innerHTML') ; do you know how I can debug an other way ? Thanks !

Comment: "//" means "from root". Likely you want "div[2]/div/a".

Comment: It should be easy to turn this into a working example. I didn't write an answer because my proposed solution wasn't easily testable.

Comment: I thought root was "/" ... But no matter, look at the two html blocs displayed, this has nonsens to have pseudo1 as text for w.text in bloc 2 because there is no pseudo1 at all... thanks tho I've tried and it worked

Comment: "/" is root. I should have said "search from root".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this.

```
print('Pseudo : ',w.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[2]/div/a").text)
```